# AngularJs autocomplete TypeError: this.source is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I have the following HTML textbox for autocomplete feature.

```
    <body  ng-controller="HomeController" ng-init="init()">
        <div class="col-xs-4 search-bar-position" >
                    <form role="search" >
                      <div class="input-group" >
                        <input auto-complete  type="text"  id ="search" value="abcd" class="form-control  text-center" placeholder="Search Products" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" style="width:400px;height:30px;" ng-change="autoComplete()" ng-model="searchChar" />
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" style="height:30px;" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
          </div>
</body>
```

AngularJS controller is as follows.

```
angular.module('gbuyRef').controller('HomeController',function ($scope,$window,$http,$cookies) {
$scope.autoComplete = function() {
        searchChar = $scope.searchChar
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/autoComplete',
            data : {"searchChar" : searchChar},
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
            // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.products = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                $scope.product_list = $scope.products.products;
                console.log($scope.product_list);
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
                $window.alert("error")
            });
    }

});
```

AngularJS directive is as follows:

```
angular.module('gbuyRef').directive('autoComplete', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            // elem is a jquery lite object if jquery is not present,
            // but with jquery and jquery ui, it will be a full jquery object.
            elem.autocomplete({
                source: scope.product_list
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When i try to use the autocomplete feature by entering into the textbox, I get the below error in firebug

**TypeError: this.source is not a function this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );**

$scope.product_list is getting the response form the backend as 
["samsung chromebook", "sony playstation 4", "sony vaio", "sony vaio 17"] when i press **s** in the textbox

I did look at other post but could not figure out the actual solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error sounds like you have not initialised `product_list` to anything prior to your HTTP request invocation. Also, I think you will need to call `autocomplete` to rebind the suggestion list every time it is updated by the HTTP request (i.e. use `$watch`).

Comment: @miqid : Could you kindly show me how to use $watch in the AngularJS directive.

Comment: Sure thing. I just took out relevant bits of the code you provided to hack a simple example to demonstrate. [JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/wuyeb/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <textarea
    placeholder="Type @ to search..."
    class="form-control"
    rows="5"
    [(ngModel)]="textFieldValue"
    mwlTextInputAutocomplete
    **[findChoices]="giveMeallTags"**
    [getChoiceLabel]="tagNamesApply">
```

That value has to be a function, my friend. Not a list, I made that mistake at first too.